# Writing Fold in terms of Map or MapThread?

Tags: functional-style, pure-function

Consider

```
Fold[f,z,{a,b,c}]
==> f[f[f[z,a],b,c]]
```

I'm looking for a way to write this (in general) using `Map` or `MapThread` (and perhaps `Flatten[#,1]&`, thinking of monadic `bind` a-la Haskell), and not using mutable variables.  In other words, the following is too easy:

```
Module[{result = z},
  Map[v \[Function]
    result = f[result, v],
   {a, b, c}]] // Last
```

and the following is not even wrong:

```
MapThread[f, {{z, f[z, a], f[f[z, a], b]}, {a, b, c}}] // Last
```

and the following is even more not even wrong (invoking Haskell's state monad); although it could be written recursively to be more general, the recursive form would just be a simulacrum of `Fold` with more functional garbage around the binding functions:

```
return[v_] := s \[Function] {v, s};
bind[m_, fv2m_] := s \[Function]
  With[{vs0 = m[s]},
    With[{
     v0 = vs0[[1]],
     s0 = vs0[[2]]},
    fv2m[v0][s0]]]

bind[
  bind[
    bind[
     return[z],
     v \[Function] return[f[v, a]]],
    v \[Function] return[f[v, b]]],
   v \[Function] return[f[v, c]]][z] // First
```

I'm beginning to think that `Fold` is its own critter, kind of a state-monad-in-disguise, inherently recursive, and not representable by `Map` and friends, which are inherently iterative. But I haven't yet been able to prove that it's not possible, even though I haven't found a solution.

Anyone happen to know?

EDIT: the reason I'm looking for this is so I can build a reactive version around the Observable/Observer pattern, which is formally dual to the Iterable/Iterator pattern, and replaces `Map` with `Subscribe`, sort-of. I do not know a reactive partner to `Fold`, and that's the ultimate objective.

Comment: I would like to help but I don't understand the computer science jargon. You can only use `Map`, `MapThread`, etc? Something recursive won't do the trick? Like `fold[fun_, lhs_, {}] := lhs; fold[fun_, lhs_, {next_, rest___}] := fold[fun, fun[lhs, next], {rest}];`

Comment: Yes, I don't want something recursive because I want to iterate (or subscribe to) the members of a sequence in memory (or that appear over time), unless there is a way to make a recursive function that "resubscribes" to the observable after making each observation (iow, the "onNext" callback unsubscribes the old observer (itself) and subscribes a new observer that has the recursive value f[f...] bound to a new variable.  Sorry for the jargon -- I was just trying to make this question short :(

Comment: Sorry to be ignorant, but what is `Subscribe` and what do you mean by *reactive*?

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by *subscribe*, *observable* and *observer*? The only *observable/observer* I learnt are from quantum mechanic, and I'm pretty sure those have nothing to do with your question.. :(

Comment: If we think of `{a, b, c}` as a sequence of values distributed in memory, i.e., an "Iterable", then `Map` or `ForEach` is a higher-order function that applies another function `f` to the values, iteratively, by invoking an "Iterator". If we think of `{a, b, c}` as a sequence of values distributed in time, i.e., an "Observable", then `Subscribe` is a higher-order function that applies another function `f` to the values in callback fashion, and we call `f` an "Observer". Take a look here http://stanford.io/1kw535m

Comment: I'm working out an Observable/Observable pair in MMA similar to the Enumerable/Enumerator (i.e., Iterable/Iterator) pair I already worked out here http://bit.ly/1jwoVYa, with a view to doing online, incremental statistics, along these lines http://bit.ly/18GcHr5

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Thanks a lot, very informative!

Answer (score 5):

If you accept to use function composition, you might use something like this:

```
g = Composition @@ (Function /@ MapThread[f, {{#, #, #}, Reverse@{a, b, c}}]);
g[z]
```

which is equal to Fold[f, z, {a, b, c}].

Comment: `Composition` and `Apply` are *definitely* acceptable.  I'm digesting this proposal some more; looks brilliant to me.

Comment: Noting also that we accomplish a right-fold by `Composition@@(Function/@MapThread[Flip@f,{{#,#,#},{a,b,c}])` where `Flip[f_]:={x,y}\[Function]f[y,x]`.  Applied to `z`, we get `f[a,f[b,f[c,z]]]`

Comment: Ok, here is a version that is pure functional and requires no rewriting tricks: `Apply[Composition, 
  Map[v \[Function] x \[Function] f[x, v], Reverse@{a, b, c}]][z]`

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered a few more things about this, so I am putting my response at top level so that it doesn't get ignored in comments, even though @user8074 absolutely gave me the ice-breaking idea.  I now believe that

```
(Composition @@ Function[v, Function[x, f[v, x]]] /@ {a, b, c})@z
```

that is,

```
Apply[Composition, Map[Function[v, Function[x, f[v, x]]], {a, b, c}]][z]
```

is exactly

```
FoldRight[f, z, {a, b, c}]
```

where

```
FoldRight[f_, z_, l_List] := Fold[Flip@f, z, Reverse@l]
```

and

```
Flip[f_] := Function[{x, y}, f[y, x]]
```

Note also that

```
Fold[f, z, l] === FoldRight[Flip@f, z, Reverse@l]
```

for any particular `l`, so `FoldRight` and `Fold` are symmetric, and `Fold` could be called `FoldLeft`.

I checked with some people and I think that it was thought to be impossible to express `Fold` in terms of `Map`, although this combination of `Map`, `Composition`, and `Apply` may be novel. I will continue to post here as I learn more from colleagues.

Comment: @Red.Cabin actually, there is a difference between FoldRight and the version with Composition. The latter acts explicitely on the variable z while, in the former version, all the argurments are on the same footing. To some extent it seems like having "curried" FoldRight

Comment: I fixed my post (I forgot to include `z` :)  I am pretty sure that `FoldRight[f_,z_,l_List]:=(Composition@@Function[v,Function[x,f[v,x]]]/@l)@z` is exactly Haskell's `foldr` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950508/haskell-foldr-and-foldl-further-explanation-and-example). I am pretty sure I can make it work on infinite, lazy lists, too.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin but `Composition` is a kind of fold when it is applied to a sequence of several arguments (traditionally function composition is a function of exactly 2 arguments and this is probably what a mathematician would understand by it).  I think you'd need to post a more mathematical question in a different forum such as SX Mathematics if you want a precise answer to the question of expressivity of `Map`.